# Identify current configuration using preprocessor directives on visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to identify the current configuration that is vs running on? configuration like debug or release or another custom configuration of mine.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5081150/507793

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5100290/3864867 for setting up preprocessor definitions (Edit: link concerns a C/C++ VS project, but is still relevant for C# project)

Comment: @Matthew yep something like that, but I really need with a custom configuration name not just DEBUG.

Comment: I think you may have to add a preprocessor definition for each build configuration and check it explicitly, would work fine if the different configurations are known upfront.  `#if Integration... #if QaBuild`, etc.

Comment: Well I find a solution or may be called a work around, I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve this just adding a new directive to my configuration and by that way knowing my current configuration.

I got a configuration called Testing and on the project configuration I just add this new definition called testing too.

[image]

```
#if Testing
      //do cool stuff 
#else
     //do more cool stuff
#endif
```